# Can a FHIR profile StructureDefinition be based on another profile StructureDefinition?

Tags: hl7-fhir

Can a StructureDefinition created as part of a FHIR profile be based on another StructureDefinition also created as part of a profile?

E.g.

The DAF-Patient StructureDefinition is part of the DAF FHIR profile and is not part of the core FHIR definition - http://www.hl7.org/fhir/daf/daf-patient.html.

Let's say you wanted to create a SecondaryCare-DAF-Patient which was based on the DAF-Patient but had further restrictions to it's elements.

Is this allowable as per the FHIR DSTU 2 specification?

Answer (score 0):

yes, the StructureDefinition.base would be http://hl7.org/fhir/StructureDefinition/daf-patient.